# Error installing ng2-redux

Tags: angular, redux

I am following https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-redux link but getting  an error on running `npm install redux ng2-redux --save`.
The stacktrace is below:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "redux" "ng2-redux" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install redux as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\desktop\redux\redux\npm-debug.log
```

Can someone tell me the cause for this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your project name in package.json, it should help

Answer (score 0):

I think your command is wrong (you try to install redux and not ng2-redux).

Go to your project folder where package.json is and execute this:

```
npm install ng2-redux --save
```

From npm help install:

```
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>
```